# What word best means "disdain for the uncouth"?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

I'm looking for a word that means: bigotry against, or disdain for, uncouth people. ('Misanthropy' is too general, I think.)   This would sort of be the converse of anti-intellectualism.   By 'uncouth people', I mean people who (example) might casually toss litter into the street and not give it a second thought, etc.

Comment: How about *snob*, *snobbish*, or *snobbery*?

Comment: Well that sort of works, but I was after a more clinical angle, not something pejorative.

Comment: Why do you think that bigotry, uncouth, and disdain are not inherently pejorative?

Comment: Disdain and uncouth certainly are pejorative.  I'm not worried about pejorative words occurring in my definition, I was just hoping for a non-pejorative word that fits that definition.
Also, the idea I'm looking to convey is not so much that the person thinks they are better than others, but more that said others don't measure up to some subjective minimum degree of grace.  (There is an implication that the one person does measure up to that standard; that's just not the focus of my desired connotation.)
Perhaps _snob_ is the best I can hope for (also: supercilious... but same shortfall.)

Comment: What about "elitist"?

Comment: I think I know what you mean: sort of "high basic standards." You sometimes hear talk of "baseline": "she has a really high baseline for acceptable behaviour."  "She is disgusted by behaviour which is below her very high baseline."

Comment: re: baseline -- Exactly, Joe Blow.

Comment: Another way to describe what I was after: looking down upon people who do things like nose-picking in public, tossing litter into the street, etc.

Comment: I must declare a vested interest as I hold a bigoted prejudice against people who throw litter in the street without a second thought.

Comment: Sorry this is off-topic, but if you want, you can un-accept an answer by clicking the check mark. On topic: Any discrepancy that can be determinable in some form is likely to appear as pejorative in most cases. *eschew low mannerisms* may apply as not-as-negative but it's still *haughty*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Supercilious' is what you are looking for.

Comment: I mentioned this one above, already, in a comment.  I feel it has some short-comings for my needs... but I've not found anything better, so I'll accept your answer.

Comment: ... but I'll change my acceptance if something better comes along.  :)

Comment: "Supercilious" is a character trait of the person *being* supercilious. It doesn't say anything about the *object* of the superciliousness. One could be supercilious about anything/anyone.

Comment: Yes, and the supercilious regard others as their inferiors.

Comment: I agree, A.E.; that was my problem with supercillious.  Perhaps I was too hasty to accept this answer (I felt obligated to except something.)

Comment: 'Accept', not 'except'. 'Supercilious' means looking down one's nose as if at an inferior (uncouth). That is understood by the English speaker. From W3:
1 : arrogantly superior : HAUGHTY, DISDAINFUL *though elated by his rank, it did not render him supercilious— Jane Austen* *translators T supercilious about the possibility of using Basic English for such international conferences— Mark Starr* *shaggy supercilious camels— L.C.Stevens*
2 : expressive of contempt : SCORNFUL, SNEERING *his lip curls in a supercilious smile*
synonyms see PROUD

Comment: Doh! Yes;  s/except/accept.  (My fingers are bad with homophones.) Ornello, I think where you and I have a disconnect is that I don't equate uncouth with inferiority.  I might judge someone as lacking good manners, but that doesn't mean I think I'm superior to them as a human being.  That's why I don't really think supercilious is perfect for my needs.

Comment: I'm truly starting to think there is no perfect one-word answer to this.

Comment: You need to give more context, and yes, that's likely. Why are so many people on here asking for a single word that means X?

Comment: [Supercilious](http://thefreedictionary.com/supercilious) is [affectation](http://thefreedictionary.com/affectation) of superiority without any particular reason to be acting like that. It's more of a showing of haughtiness. Oh, sure, it can be because one *is* haughty, but one could be such without expressing such.

Answer (score 1):

"Intellectual snobbery" pretty much fits the bill.

It's a pejorative term for prejudice against people or pursuits who/which are perceived (the implication is, wrongly perceived) as insufficiently intellectual.

An example of intellectual snobbery: A person prefers opera to comic books purely because opera is perceived as 'high art' and comic books are perceived as 'low art'. They find opera more intellectually respectable than comic books. That person is an intellectual snob; they are displaying intellectual snobbery.

---

Oh, you mean disdain for impoliteness? That's not "the converse of anti-intellectualism". Intellectuals can be plenty impolite (and often are - check your nearest academic listserv for examples).

If you want a word for 'excessive concern for politeness and decorum' then you could try 'fuddy-duddy' or 'prude' (although 'prude' can have the addition connotation that the excessive concern is specifically for *sexual* decorum).

If the person is excessively concerned about minor rules being broken then 'prig' might work, but it sounds pretty archaic now. The children in the E. Nesbit novels spend quite a bit of time calling one another 'prigs':

> "The only thing is - don't you be a prig, that's all. You keep your eyes open and if you feel priggishness coming on just stop in time"

(*The Railway Children*, 1906)

Comment: Despite the pejorative aspect, that's a good fit for entertainment... but not for things like nose-picking in public, tossing litter into the street, etc.

Comment: Regarding your revised answer:  (1) impoliteness is but one form of 'couthlessness'  (er... sorry) (2) I don't think disdain for (ex) throwing trash in the street is an 'excessive concern', and (3) nor is it a minor rule (in the sense that it is a pretty clear indicator of character.)  I absolutely love the word 'prig' for other literary reasons, but: all your suggestions seem inherently negative towards the person casting judgement, which was what I wanted to avoid for this instance.  For the example behavior I gave (littering,) I believe indignation is warranted, and thus not antisocial.

Comment: Well, if you want a word that means "bigotry against" uncouth people, it's going to be pejorative. Bigotry is never good! ;)

Answer (score 1):

While not considered neutral, *haughty* tends to be one who disdains those below him.

I understand that the idea of superiority is not intended but it would be understood that disdain of bad manners would strongly imply a connection between bad manners and the people who would employ them.

Comment: I believe you are right about that, SrJoven.  Perhaps my requirements were unreasonable.

Answer (score -1):

'Smug' is also a possibility. It is worth considering at least.

Comment: Please feel free to edit your other answer to include this information, and perhaps explain how it answers the question.